# Выделение дин. памяти в функциях

Tags: c, указатели, memory

Если я буду динамически выделять память в функции, то она будет храниться в "куче" или в стеке?

Comment: Насколько я помню динамическая память выделяется в куче не зависимо от того, где она была запрошена. Выделение подобной памяти в стек является исключительной ситуацией, к примеру принудительным образом или в результате оптимизации компилятором.

Comment: Если вызываете malloc/calloc/.../strdup/asprintf и т.п., то в куче, если пишете что-то типа `int n; scanf("%d", &n); int a[n]; ...`, то в стеке (а так, смотря что Вы называете словами "динамически выделять память")

Comment: А можно динамически выделить память не в функции? Точнее, да, можно.. Но всё-таки?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Там, где вы выделили память, там она и будет "храниться".:)

Ели вы выделили экстент памяти в динамической области памяти, то он и будет частью этой памяти.

Другое дело - где будет храниться адрес выделенного экстента памяти, возвращаемый функцией выделения памяти. Если он будет храниться в локальной переменной функции, то после выхода и функции эта локальная переменная прекратит свое существование, и тем самым адрес выделенной памяти будет утерян, в результате чего будет иметь место утечка памяти.

Поэтому если вы хотите сохранить этот адрес, то либо вам следует его возвращать из функции, либо объявлять соответствующий указатель на указатель как параметр функции.

Рассмотрите следующие объявления

```
void f( void )
{
    int *p = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
}
```

В этой функции выделяется память, адрес которой присваивается указателю `p`. После выхода из функции локальная переменная `p` прекратит свое существование, и адрес выделенной памяти будет утерян.

Другой пример.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void f( int *p )
{
    p = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
}

int main( void )
{
    int *p = NULL;

    f( p );
}
```

В функции этой программы параметр `p` является локальной переменной функции, которая была инициализирована значением `NULL` одноименного аргумента  `p`. Этой локальной переменной был присвоен адрес выделенной памяти. Однако после выхода из функции эта переменная прекратила свое существование, следовательно, этот адрес выделенной памяти опять был утерян.

Чтобы не потерять этот адрес выделенной памяти и "донести" его в целости и сохранности до вызывающего кода, функцию следует объявить одним из следующих способов

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int * f( void )
{
    int *p = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
    return p;
}

int main( void )
{
    int *p = NULL;

    p = f();

    //...

    free( p );
}
```

Или

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void f( int **p )
{
    *p = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
}

int main( void )
{
    int *p = NULL;

    f( &p );

    //...

    free( p );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В куче.

В стеке память по определению не динамическая :)

И выделится там, только если вызовите `alloca`.